# Fill out a form, submit and get a response with scrapy

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy

i'm learning to automate some web tasks, and i have this code to fill out a form using python scrapy. It takes essentially mongolian cyrrilic sentences and translate it into traditional mongolian script. What i want to do is to read the sentences into a list from a file ("test.txt") and then to get the translation back and print it in the console.

```
import scrapy

class BichigSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "bichig"
    allowed_domains = ["http://trans.mglip.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://trans.mglip.com/EnglishC2T.aspx"]
    
    def LoadListofSentences(self):
        output = []
        with open('test.txt', 'r',encoding='utf-8') as f:
            for el in f:
                output.append(el)
        return output

    def parse(self, response):
        ListeSent = self.LoadListofSentences()
        for sent in ListeSent:
            formdata = {'inputCyrillic_ID': sent}
            yield scrapy.http.FormRequest.from_response(response,
                                            formdata=formdata,
                                            clickdata={'name': 'ButtonTran_ID'},
                                            callback=self.parse1)

    def parse1(self, response):
        print(response.css('outPutTraditonalM_ID::text').get())
```

Content of file "test.txt", located in the folder spiders with the init file:

```
Хоёр мянга арван гурван оны өвлийн цагаан будан татсан гэрэлт өдөр Өвөрхангай аймгийн театрт Монгол найргийн дархан цэц Дэндэвийн Пүрэвдорж гуайн нэрэмжит “Болор цом” наадмыг жулдрайхан би эхлүүлж байлаа.
Үндсэндээ түрүү жилийн эзэн дараа жилийнхээ цомыг нээдэг тэрхүү уламжлалын дагуу 30 жилийнх нь тэгш ойд түрүүлсний хувьд Пүрэвдорж гуайнхаа наадмыг “Өвгөд минь өндрийн салхи болохуйд” шүлгээрээ нээж байсан.
Тэрхүү хувь заяагаа би дандаа сүслэн боддог.
Пүрэвдорж гуай өөрөө санаачилж эхлүүлсэн, анхны түрүүг нь хүртсэн авшигтай эл наадмыг 80 насных нь их ойгоор өөрийнх нь нэрэмжит болон хүмүүн биеийг олсон халуун голомт Өврийн хангай нутагт нь болоход нээнэ гэдэг хувь заяа гэхээс өөр яалтай.
Шүлгээ дуудчихаад, шүлгээ уншихаар гараанаас эргэх гэж буй морьд шиг тогтож ядан байгаа найрагчдынхаа дунд орж ирэхэд омог төгөлдөр байсан даа.
Эрдэнэ-Очир ах минь, Хөөдөө ах минь, дархад Мийгаа ах минь, Лхамсүрэнжавын Ганзул ах минь бүгд шүлгээ унших гээд ирийтэл зогсож байсан сан.
Мөн ч алтанхан сайхан он жил байж шүү.
Наадмын урьд өдөр “Уран үгсийн чуулган”-д Монголын яруу найргийн их оргилууд Бавуугийн Лхагвасүрэн, Тангадын Галсан, Пунцагийн Бадарч нарын тоосон дунд орж цомын эзэн хэмээн Ичинхорлоо найрагчаар зарлуулж байснаа одоо эргээд бодох нь ээ, айх ч шиг.
Их найргийн бурхдын сүрд дарагдсан бахдал дүүрэн он цаг минь.
```

But i get this error after writing scrapy crawl bichig in the command line:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\Test\Scripts\scrapy-script.py", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(execute())
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\Test\lib\site-packages\scrapy\cmdline.py", line 124, in execute
    cmds = _get_commands_dict(settings, inproject)
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\Test\lib\site-packages\scrapy\cmdline.py", line 52, in _get_commands_dict
    cmds = _get_commands_from_module('scrapy.commands', inproject)
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\Test\lib\site-packages\scrapy\cmdline.py", line 33, in _get_commands_from_module
    for cmd in _iter_command_classes(module):
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\Test\lib\site-packages\scrapy\cmdline.py", line 20, in _iter_command_classes
    for module in walk_modules(module_name):
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\Test\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\misc.py", line 88, in walk_modules
    submod = import_module(fullpath)
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\Test\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\Test\lib\site-packages\scrapy\commands\parse.py", line 10, in <module>
    from scrapy.utils import display
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\Test\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\display.py", line 5, in <module>
    import ctypes
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\Test\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _ctypes:the specified module could not be found
```

Can somebody help me please with this or any other viable solution?

Comment: That problem is not related to your code, but your Python environment is somehow missing the `_ctypes` library. I might recommend reinstalling Python...

Answer (score 0):

Solved! I needed to reinstall python that's all.